# Force Landscape in UWP app regardless of device

Tags: c#, xaml, landscape, uwp

I have a win10 app, I'm working on and it runs in landscape when on tablets/pc's But when it goes onto a phone it switches to portrait. If I switch it to landscape in the designer it looks fine, but when I run it, it still defaults to portrait. In the application manifest I have only the landscape and landscape flipped modes supported.

Comment: don't you have rotation lock turned on on your phone? :)

Comment: So you did set the initialrotationpreference? ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700342.aspx )

Comment: I just checked the initialrotationpreference, and apparently those are set via the application manifest, which as I mentioned previously are already set. I did read on the url something about if the rotation lock was set then it would still be honored (although that seems counter intuitive) ie so if you have it locked to be portrait it would still go landscape? 
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>

Comment: Can you force it in code by doing:             DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape | DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped;

Comment: @igrali, When I do something like this I have only the last option. In this case: `LandscapeFlipped`.